# What is the most Pythonic way to find all Nones in a list of lists?

Tags: python

Is there a better Pythonic way to find all Nones in a list of lists than this code?

```
    def find_nones_locations(lst):
         none_locations = []
         for i in range(len(lst)):
              for j in range(len(lst)):
                   if lst[i][j] is None:
                        none_locations.append((i,j))
         return none_locations
```

Comment: Why do you check `(i, j)`?

Comment: Was not needed, I have edited the code

Comment: Instead of `range` use `enumerate`. i.e. `for i, val in enumerate(lst):`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to do it in one shot, but I'm not sure it's necessarily better than a legible loop:

```
none_locations = [(i, j) for i, row in enumerate(lst) for j, elem in enumerate(row) if elem is None]
```

Nested loops in comprehensions follow the same order they do in plain code. There's no good reason not to use a plain loop:

```
none_locations = []
for i, row in enumerate(lst):
    for j, elem in enumerate(row):
        if elem is None:
            none_locations.append((i, j))
```

The only potential improvement over your code is the use of the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) generator. Any time you need both the index and the value of an iterable, that's generally the pythonic way to get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to clean up the code a bit:

```
def find_nones_locations(lst):
     none_locations = []
     for i, sublst in enumerate(lst):
          for j, item in enumerate(sublist):
               if item is None:
                    none_locations.append((i,j))
     return none_locations
```